# Is there a solution for $2^{n-1}\equiv 2^{16}+1\mod n$ or $2^{n-1}\equiv 2^{26}+1\mod n$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Related to this question : [Can I find all solutions of $2^{n-1}\equiv k\mod n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3149076/can-i-find-all-solutions-of-2n-1-equiv-k-mod-n)

> Does one of the congruences $$2^{n-1}\equiv 2^{16}+1\mod n$$ and $$2^{n-1}\equiv 2^{26}+1\mod n$$ have an integer solution $n>1$ ?

Enzo Creti checked the second congruences upto $\ 127\cdot 10^9\ $. No solution was found.

The first congruence has no solution below $10^9$

Comment: $$n = 4\ 428\ 169\ 422\ 323$$ solves $$2^{n-1}\equiv 2^{16}+1\mod n$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of solutions to $2^{n-1}\equiv 2^{26}+1\pmod{n}$: 567621107057 and  804008475239.