# Is $\ 101\ $ the only solution of $\ 2^{n-1}\equiv 203\mod n\ $?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I wonder whether the congruence $$2^{n-1}\equiv 203\mod n$$ with integer $n>1$ has only the solution $n=101$.

Up to $n=10^9$, there is no solution.

Since $n$ must be odd, every prime factor $p$ of $n$ must have $203$ as a quadratic residue modulo $p$ and $2^k\equiv 203 \mod p$ must be solvable.

Deeper analysis reveals that the smallest possible prime factors are $17$ and $53$.

- If $17$ is a prime factor , $n$ must be of the form $136k + 85$.
- If $53$ is a prime factor , $n$ must be of the form $2756k +477$.

Comment: how can you say that every prime factor must have $203$ as a quadratic residue modulo $p$? Could you elaborate?

Comment: @vidyarthi  Since $n$ is odd , $n-1$ is even , hence $2^{n-1}$ a perfect square.

Comment: Assuming $2^{n-1}\equiv 203\pmod n$, can you determine $n\mod 3$ or $n\mod 4$?

Comment: Is this question about $203$ and $n=101$ in particular, or is it really asking the general question, how to determine the greatest $n$ satisfying $2^{n-1} \equiv r$ (mod $n$), and/or whether a greatest $n$ always exists? If in fact there is a greatest $n$ for every given $r$, and the law of it can be even roughly determined, it might be unnecessary in the posted case to test values of $n$ beyond a limit far less than $10^9$.

Comment: @EdwardPorcella This question is only about $203$, the smallest case for which I could not find a solution, even with several tricks. I am actually interested in the general case, but the answer to this question is what Max answered. Since no further information was given by Max, I assume that he used more or less brute force.

Comment: Do you mean $203$ was the smallest number for which you were not sure you had found, or knew how to find, the largest $n$? I have been using the WolframAlpha calculator, but evidently its search range is limited since for $203$ it gives greatest $n=101$.

Comment: @EdwardPorcella $203$ was the smallest case, for which I did not find a solution exceeding the given number. In this case, $101$ does not exceed $203$ and I could not find a second solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The next solution is $n=33191065315201$.

Comment: It seems to answer the question when I read it.  We have another solution, which is what the OP seems to ask.

Comment: @egreg while this is not as good as a complete solution (which might be impossible or extremely tough), this is an extremely valuable answer and a counterexample to the conjecture in the question. Why do you disagree?

Comment: Because it's just a number without any justification. Anyway, I'll retract the comment.

Comment: This is actually what I wanted : A second solution. @MaxAlekseyev Did you find the solution by brute force or did you use some trick ?

Comment: @Peter: Yes, there are some tricks -- see my updated answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3186676